# Exec Base procedure in SSRS with Parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, parameters

I have an SSRS report that is calling on one Stored Procedure to Execute, which updates a table in the database.  Then I run a report on the data in the table utilizing another stored procedure.

What I would like to do be able to pass a parameter from the report to the Stored Procedure.  Here is a sample of what I am doing.

```
StoredProcedure
Select 
HospCode
TxnCode
TxnAmt
into
TxnData
From
Data
Where
TxnDate Between @Start and @End

Report- 
Exec StoredProcedure

Select
HospCode
Sum(TxnAmt) Over(Partition By HospCode)
From
TxnData
Order By HospCode
```

Yes the Parameters are declared in the SP.  I would like the User running the report to be able to choose the date range, then have that passed onto the Stored Procedure.

I can do this with individual Procedures very easily but The Stored Procedure is a building block that quite a few reports will use- so rather than have to copy and paste or retype, I would just like to call it up.

Is this possible.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logic but ensure the stored procedures are maintained if changes are required.
In SSRS you would pass Start date and End Date to base stored procedure which will be passed to sub stored procedure.

Test data generated for testing ..

```
create table Data (HospCode int, TxnCode int, TxnAmt money, TxnDate date)

insert into Data (HospCode, TxnCode, TxnAmt, TxnDate)
select 1, 1, 10, '2014-09-11'
union all
select 1, 1, 10, '2014-09-12'
union all
select 1, 2, 10, '2014-09-11'
union all
select 2, 2, 10, '2014-09-11'
```

Base Stored procedure: You will need to create a temp table to return data from the sub stored procedure. Ensure the temp table must have the same field and data types returned from the sub stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.someSPbase(@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE)
AS
BEGIN

    IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB.dbo.#TempData') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #TempData;

    CREATE TABLE #TempData(
                HospCode int
                , TxnCode int
                , TxnAmt money
            );

    INSERT INTO #TempData(HospCode, TxnCode, TxnAmt)
    EXEC dbo.someSPSub1 @StartDate, @EndDate


    SELECT HospCode
        , SUM(TxnAmt) OVER (Partition By HospCode) AS TxnAmtTotal
        FROM #TempData;
END
```

Sub stored procedure called from base stored procedure above:

```
    CREATE PROC dbo.someSPSub1(@StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE)
AS 
BEGIN
        Select 
            HospCode
            ,TxnCode
            ,TxnAmt
            From Data
            Where TxnDate Between @StartDate and @EndDate

END
```